Creating a subset that only includes columns that have a certain value in a certain vector
Input:
library(ISLR)
data("NCI60")

cancers <- NCI60$labs
gene_counts <- table(cancers)
g3 <- names(gene_counts[gene_counts > 3])
g3

subset_NCI60 <- NCI60[cancers %in% g3]
subset_NCI60$labs

Output:
[1] "BREAST"   "CNS"      "COLON"    "LEUKEMIA" "MELANOMA" "NSCLC"    "OVARIAN" 
[8] "RENAL"


 [1] "CNS"         "CNS"         "CNS"         "RENAL"       "BREAST"     
 [6] "CNS"         "CNS"         "BREAST"      "NSCLC"       "NSCLC"      
[11] "RENAL"       "RENAL"       "RENAL"       "RENAL"       "RENAL"      
[16] "RENAL"       "RENAL"       "BREAST"      "NSCLC"       "RENAL"      
[21] "UNKNOWN"     "OVARIAN"     "MELANOMA"    "PROSTATE"    "OVARIAN"    
[26] "OVARIAN"     "OVARIAN"     "OVARIAN"     "OVARIAN"     "PROSTATE"   
[31] "NSCLC"       "NSCLC"       "NSCLC"       "LEUKEMIA"    "K562B-repro"
[36] "K562A-repro" "LEUKEMIA"    "LEUKEMIA"    "LEUKEMIA"    "LEUKEMIA"   
[41] "LEUKEMIA"    "COLON"       "COLON"       "COLON"       "COLON"      
[46] "COLON"       "COLON"       "COLON"       "MCF7A-repro" "BREAST"     
[51] "MCF7D-repro" "BREAST"      "NSCLC"       "NSCLC"       "NSCLC"      
[56] "MELANOMA"    "BREAST"      "BREAST"      "MELANOMA"    "MELANOMA"   
[61] "MELANOMA"    "MELANOMA"    "MELANOMA"    "MELANOMA"

My problem:
Only "BREAST" "CNS" "COLON" "LEUKEMIA" "MELANOMA" "NSCLC" "OVARIAN" and "RENAL" should appear in the second output. What am I doing wrong?
subset <- NCI60[NCI60$labs %in% g3, ]

I know this is the correct way, but when I do, my R throws this error:
> subset <- NCI60[NCI60$labs %in% g3, ]
    Error in NCI60[NCI60$labs %in% g3, ] : incorrect number of dimensions


Do
> subset_NCI60 <- lapply(NCI60, `[`, NCI60$labs %in% g3)
> sort(unique(subset_NCI60$labs))  ## check
[1] "BREAST"   "CNS"      "COLON"    "LEUKEMIA" "MELANOMA" "NSCLC"    "OVARIAN"  "RENAL"  

Reason
NCI60 is a list containing a matrix data and labs referring to the rows of data. So we need subset both using the bracket `[`() function.
> str(NCI60)
List of 2
 $ data: num [1:64, 1:6830] 0.3 0.68 0.94 0.28 0.485 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:64] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:6830] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ labs: chr [1:64] "CNS" "CNS" "CNS" "RENAL" ...

